# Run a script every few secconds

Tags: linux

I have a php script that i need to run every 4 seconds for one hour a day, what is the best way to do this. I look up a way of using cron and sleep and also watch but what would be the best way of doing this over all?

Watch

```
watch -n10 command args
```

cron:

```
* * * * * /foo/bar/your_script
* * * * * sleep 4; /foo/bar/your_script
* * * * * sleep 8; /foo/bar/your_script
* * * * * sleep 12; /foo/bar/your_script
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, it seems there isn't a simple way to do this using cron, since cron has a granularity of 60 seconds. Basically you would have to find a workaround.

One workaround, that you seem to have already come across, is to have multiple events with offset start times. E.g. [Running a cron every 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619362/running-a-cron-every-30-seconds)

Another is to do more granular scheduling within the PHP script itself. E.g. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4672451/5569286)

At that point it might make sense to then also make your PHP script a daemon process: [Run php script as daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036654/run-php-script-as-daemon-process)